# Avoid global variable in a python util file

Tags: python

I have a *`utilities.py`* file for my python project.  It contains only util functions, for example `is_float(string)`, `is_empty(file)`, etc.

Now I want to have a function `is_valid(number)`, which has to:

1. read from a file, *`valid.txt`*, which contains all numbers which are valid, and load them onto a map/set.
2. check the map for the presence of `number` and return True or False.

This function is called often, and running time should be as small as possible. I don't want to read open and read *`valid.txt`* everytime the function is called. The only solution I have come up with is to use a global variable, `valid_dict`, which is loaded once from *`valid.txt`* when *`utilities.py`* is imported. The loading code is written as main in *`utilities.py`*.

My question is how do I do this without using a global variable, as it is considered bad practice? What is a good design pattern for doing such a task without using globals? Also note again that this is a util file, so there should ideally be no main as such, just functions.

Comment: One way is to use a closure, are you familiar with the concept?

Comment: "... using a global variable ... is considered bad practice" - It isn't bad practice. Feel free to do exactly that.

Comment: that would **only be global inside of utilities.py** ... everywhere else that would be a "module level variable"

Comment: Robᵩ's comment is correct, but I'd like to add some detail that explains why: if you never modify the map/set/whateverdatastructure, then you're not using global variables. You're using a global *constant*. That's perfectly fine. The problem with global variables is that it's hard to track down where they were modified. If you never modify them, then the only remaining potential problem is namespace polution, but Joran pointed out that the structure would only be in the module's namespace. This is the most simple solution, and is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: It would be considered good Python style to name the dictionary `_valid_dict`. This indicates to the reader that this object is for internal use in the `utilities` module.

Comment: Of the 3 possible solutions 1. Using globals, as mentioned in the comments above, 2. using closures as in cdarke 's answer 3. Using static variables as Elmar Peise pointed out, which one is the best way to do it, from a design pattern standpoint as well as being pythonic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is a simple example of a *closure*.  The dictionary, `cache`, is encapsulated within the outer function (`load_func`), but remains in scope of the inner, even when it is returned.  Notice that `load_func` returns the inner function as an object, it does not call it.

In `utilities.py`:

```
def _load_func(filename):

    cache = {}

    with open(filename) as fn:
        for line in fn:
            key, value = line.split()
            cache[int(key)] = value

    def inner(number):
        return number in cache

    return inner

is_valid = _load_func('valid.txt')
```

In `__main__`:

```
from utilities import is_valid                  # or something similar

if is_valid(42):
    print(42, 'is valid')
else:
    print(42, 'is not valid')
```

The dictionary (`cache`) creation could have been done using a dictionary comprehension, but I wanted you to concentrate on the closure.

Comment: This looks like a solid answer to the question, with some useful info. However, I'm inclined to think that using a global variable may still be a preferable solution - it seems a little more readable to me.

Comment: Fair enough, its your choice.  One of the advantages of using a closure is that the persistent object (I won't call it a global in this context) is encapsulated within the outer function.  Using a global means you need to be careful of a name collision within the same module.  Using a closure means that the function could be extracted and reused in any other module.  However if the module is relatively small and uncomplicated then using a conventional global should be OK.  I'll end with observing that code rarely gets smaller or less complicated over time...

Comment: Am am new to the concept of closures, but let me know if I have understood this correctly. Every time I need to call the `is_valid` function, I will first load it using `is_valid = load_func('valid.txt')`. This basically 'creates' the function for future use, and this is where the loading happens, only once. Subsequent calls to `is_valid` will *not* end up opening and loading the file again.

Comment: Although the above (wonderfully) eliminates the need of globals, it breaks my API, which requires the need for only one `is_valid` function. I should not be required to load the function first using `is_valid = load_func('valid.txt')` right? Or have I understood it incorrectly? If yes, please let me know the correct way to do this.

Comment: You have the right idea.  The call to `load_func()` will be executed when the module is imported.  There is only one `is_valid` function (you might want to rename `inner()` in my example).  When you do an assignment in python the name on the left-hand-side is a *reference* to the object returned from the right-hand side.  You can have as many names referring to a function object as you like, but there will still only be one function object.

Comment: I should add that you have the line `is_valid = load_func('valid.txt')` in the module along with `load_func()`.  That will then be executed automagically on import.  The user code does not explicitly call `load_func()`.  There is a good case for calling it `_load_func()` so that it is (under normal circumstances) invisible.  I will modify my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 3):

The variable `valid_dict` would not be global but local to `utilities.py`. It would only become global if you did something like `from utilities import *`.  Now that *is* considered bad practice when you're developing a package.

However, I have used a trick in cases like this that essentially requires a static variable:  Add an argument `valid_dict={}` to `is_valid()`.  This dictionary will be instantiated only once and each time the function is called the same `dict` is available in `valid_dict`.

```
def is_valid(number, valid_dict={}):
    if not valid_dict:
        # first call to is_valid: load valid.txt into valid_dict
    # do your check
```

Do *NOT* assign to `valid_dict` in the `if`-clause but *only modify* it: e.g., by setting keys `valid_dict[x] = y` or using something like `valid_dict.update(z)`.

(PS: Let me know if this is considered "dirty" or "un-pythonic".)